# Force hotspot to make frequent GCs?

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

I am benchmarking a server process, in Java and it appears that Hotspot is not making many GCs, but when it does, its hitting performance massively.

Can I force hotspot to make frequent smaller GCs, rather than a few massive long GCs?

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the GC to parallel or concurrent.
Here's a link to the documentation.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html

Answer (score 1):

Interferring with when the GC is called, is usually a bad idea. 
A better approach would be tuning the sizes of eden, survivor and old space if you have problems with performance of the gc.

If a full sweep has to be done it does not really matter how often it was called, the speed will always be relatively slow, the only fast gc calls are those in eden and survivor space.

So increasing eden and survivor space might solve your problem, but unfortunately a good memory profiling is rather time consuming and complex to perform.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html
(link stolen from other answer) also gives the options on how to configure that if necessary. -XX:NewRatio=2 or -XX:NewRatio=3 might increase your speed but it might also slow it up. Unfortunately that is very application dependant.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the JVM to do a garbage collection programatically by: [System.gc()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc%28%29). Please note that the Javadoc says that this is only a suggestion. You can try calling this before getting into a critical section where you don't want the GC performance penalty.

Comment: The thing about this is that it's literally a suggestion. You're saying: "Hey, Garbage Collector, could you come give me a cleanup please?" It's fully allowed to respond "Lolnope!"

Answer (score 0):

You can increase how often the GC is performed by decreasing the young/new sizes or call gc more often.  This doesn't mean you will pause for a less time, just that it will happen mroe often.

The best way to reduce the impact of GC is to memory profile your application and reduce the amount of garbage you are producing.  This will not only make your code faster, but reduce how often and for how long each GC occurs.

In the more extreme case, you can reduce how often the GC occurs to less than once per day, removing it as an issue all together.